# Why I am getting number as output when I'm using array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr = ['abc','def'];
arr = arr.push('ghi')
console.log(arr);
```

For the above code why am I getting the output as 3 instead of getting the output as array.
Also if you get the solution to the problem, please give the desired code.

Comment: You dont need to write `arr = arr.push('ghi')` just write `arr.push('ghi')` and it should work

Comment: replace `arr = arr.push('ghi')` with `arr.push('ghi')` because `push()` returns the length of the new array (and please always check the docs first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `arr.push('ghi')` instead of `arr = arr.push('ghi')`

```js
let arr = ['abc','def'];
arr.push('ghi')
console.log(arr);
```

According to MDN

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

So when you store the return value of `arr.push()` function into `arr`, this returns you the `length` of the array after pushing the new value. So the value of `arr` becomes `3`.